# Allow my ip access the entire site and all another to a subfoler with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this layout

```
aplication
public
--index.php
soon
--css
--img
--index.html
.htaccess
```

Right not I have this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 48.42.126.xx
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

This gives me (my ip) full access to the entire page, but all other ip get a server error message.

I still want my ip to access the entire site but all other ip should only access what is in the soon folder (css, img and index.html).

Which is the best solution for it in my .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your content in root .htaccess with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^48\.42\.126\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/soon/
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks!
My IP works fine, I can access the whole site. But when I visit from another IP I get the error message "Forbidden - operation is understood but refused".

Comment: From other IP only requests starting from /soon/ will work. Try it from a new browser.